# Epsilon-delta definition of limit reformulation

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

[image]

I was thinking how I could interpret the epsilon-delta definition of limits so that it could be done using more symbols rather than natural language. I'm not sure if this formulation of the definition of adequate, but I will try to explain my thought-process. Is this formulation of the epsilon-delta definition of limits consistent with how most people use the definition? If not, what can I improve?

We are required to have $\epsilon >0$, so I include in such a way that it can be done for a primary subderivation. Then, we cannot just have by magic a $\delta$, so I make sure that it either derives from $\epsilon$ or at least derived in a 'proper' way. Then we have the part where I am most concerned: the quantified statement. So I try to make everything nice and tidy for the secondary subderivation, and I have a pair of mutually redundant statements, the second and third conjuncts in the antecedent, but include them anyways, because if someone wanted to derive them formally, I save them the effort. Then we have the expected part in the consequent.

I apologize if I sound like I have no idea what I'm doing, for that is mostly true. I acknowledge that conjuncts could be neatly organized in more brackets, to make it more formal but I decided against that.

Comment: A natural language-free symbolic definition of limits that takes two lines to state? Thanks, I hate it. :-P

Comment: Writing $\lnot x = c \land 0 < |x - c| < \delta$ is redundant. You can just write $0 < |x - c| < \delta$.

Comment: @TheoBendit, you're right about the redundancy, however, I did acknowledge it, but maybe it got lost in my word salad. That's partially why I tried to come up with this formal language definition, I tend to word salad in my proofs, and then I struggle to understand my own train of thought.

Comment: If it helps you understand the definition better, then go for it. However, I really would discourage you from quoting it in a proof, since most people find natural language much easier to read than huge strings of symbols (that's why the language is considered "natural"!).

Comment: @TheoBendit, then is my formulation of the definition equivalent to what is used in natural language?

Comment: Sort of, sort of not. The impression I get is that you're trying to include premises such as "$f$ is defined on an open interval $I$ with the point $c \in I$ removed", and other parts that would normally stated up front (in natural language) into your string of symbols (which is the first line). If this is the case, then "$\forall x \in I(\lnot x = c \implies \exists y \in \Bbb{R}, f(x) = x)$ is strong enough to say $f$ is a function from $I \setminus \{c\}$ to $\Bbb{R}$, as functions also require uniqueness as well. It's fine if you state that $f$ is a function in natural language though.

Comment: Why do you use $\neg x = c$ instead of $x\neq c$ (for example)?

Comment: @Fakemistake, for the purposes of $\neg E$, which is just how most people say contradiction. If a proof needed negation elimination, we would need a $\neg$ sign. Otherwise, we would need another inference rule, or reason through natural language that $x=c, ..., x\neq c$, therefore contradiction; but I'm here to not use natural language. Or we just translate the symbols back to what I wrote. I just save the translation step.

Comment: The difference between $\lnot x=c$ and $x\neq c$ is what programmers call "syntactic sugar"--it makes no real difference to the structure of the statement, and it can be undone just by defining $\neq$ in terms of $\lnot$ and $=$ and applying the definition. More significant is the interpretation of $0<|x-c|<\delta,$ which really is $0<|x-c| \land |x-c|<\delta,$ where $0<|x-c|$ turns out not-so-obviously to be equivalent to $\lnot(x=c)$.

Answer (score 1):

For fun, let's workshop this a little. The following is a definition of a limit, including natural language:

> Suppose $c \in \Bbb{R}$, $I$ is a bounded$^*$ open interval containing $c$, and $f : I \setminus \{c\} \to \Bbb{R}$ is a function. Then, for $L \in \Bbb{R}$, we say $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$ if,
> $$(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in I \setminus \{c\})(|x - c| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(c)| < \varepsilon).$$

If we truly want to make this self-contained, we probably should symbolically define what it means to be an open interval, and what it means to be a function between two sets.

A set $I$ is a non-empty bounded open interval if there exist $a, b \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $a < b$ and $x \in I \iff a < x < b$. As a daunting string of symbols, we mean
$$(\exists a, b \in \Bbb{R})(a < b \land (\forall x \in \Bbb{R})(x \in I \iff a < x < b)).$$

A set $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ if it is a relation (i.e. $f \subseteq A \times B$) such that, for all $x \in A$, there exists a **unique** $y \in B$ such that $(a, b) \in f$ (we say $f(a) = b$ for short). In symbols, $f : I \setminus \{c\} \to \Bbb{R}$ is a function if
$$(f \subseteq (I \setminus \{c\}) \times \Bbb{R}) \land (\forall x \in I \setminus \{c\})(\exists y \in \Bbb{R})(\forall y' \in \Bbb{R})((x, y) \in f \land ((x, y')\in f \implies y'=y)).$$

So, with this in mind, the way I'd express this purely symbolically is with the following nightmare of symbols:

\begin{align*}
&(\forall c \in \Bbb{R})(\forall I \in \mathcal{P}(\Bbb{R}))(\forall f \subseteq (I \setminus \{c\}) \times\Bbb{R})(\forall L \in \Bbb{R}) \\
&\Bigg(\bigg((\exists a, b \in \Bbb{R})(a < b \land (\forall x \in \Bbb{R})(x \in I \iff a < x < b)) \land \, \\
&(\forall x \in I \setminus \{c\})(\exists y \in \Bbb{R})(\forall y' \in \Bbb{R})((x, y) \in f \land ((x, y')\in f \implies y'=y))\bigg) \\
&\implies\bigg(\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L  \iff (\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in I \setminus \{c\}) \\
&(|x - c| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(c)| < \varepsilon)\bigg)\Bigg),
\end{align*}
where $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{R})$ is how I'm notating the power set.

Note that things like the power set and the subset relation, despite being symbols, could also be broken down further too, e.g. $A \subseteq B$ is defined to be $x \in A \implies x \in B$.

(Note: it's probable that I've made an error somewhere, possibly just mismatched parentheses, possibly something more grave. If you spot it, feel free to edit this answer.

---

$^*$ Boundedness is only included to make the definition a little easier to write symbolically. The same definition would work for any open interval containing $c$ (or any set containing an open interval containing $c$, or any set which has $c$ as an *accumulation* point). Indeed, this is one of the downsides of being so precise: you lose some flexibility in the definition.

Comment: I would like to point out for the purposes of derivation that tries to emulate natural deduction, without introducing another rule of inference, like if you suppose $\epsilon >0 \Rightarrow ...$, if your rules of inference allow you to 'absorb' the antecedent from the material conditional, then that is fine. So the rule I need is $P(a) \Rightarrow ...a...$ then $\forall P(x)(...x...)$ where P is an n-place predicate and $a$ is an unnamed term. Is there a rule that allows us to do that?